# Old R code which used to work now gives an error: `vars` must be a character vector

Tags: r

I am rerunning 2 year old code which uses an already deprecated package `tcR` - software to perform repertoire analysis of the T cell receptors/immunoglobulins.

I am facing an issue when calling a function which calculates morisita index of similarity between the 2 repertoires (code used to work just fine before):
Here I am using a list of datasets of individual T cell receptor sequences with their frequencies to calculate Morisita indices of dissimilarity.

```
> repOverlap(list, 'morisita', 'nuc', .norm = F, .verbose = F)
Error: `vars` must be a character vector.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
`vars` must be a character vector.
Backtrace:
 1. tcR::repOverlap(l, "morisita", "nuc", .norm = F, .verbose = F)
 4. dplyr::grouped_df(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
`vars` must be a character vector.
Backtrace:
    x
 1. \-tcR::repOverlap(l, "morisita", "nuc", .norm = F, .verbose = F)
 2.   +-base::as.data.frame(...)
 3.   +-dplyr::summarise(...)
 4.   \-dplyr::grouped_df(...)
```

I had a feeling that that would have to do with some incompatibility with the packages that have been updated since I have last used the code but after extensive googling and trying to update/reinstall stuff the issue wouldn't get fixed.

Does someone have an idea?
In case it helps here is the path to the repOverlap function of the above mentioned tcR package: https://rdrr.io/cran/tcR/src/R/repoverlap.R (and https://rdrr.io/cran/tcR/src/R/measures.R for the morisita function)
And the session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tcR_2.2.4      igraph_1.2.4   reshape2_1.4.3 gridExtra_2.3  dplyr_1.0.7    ggplot2_3.1.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1         ggpubr_0.2         pillar_1.6.1       compiler_3.5.3     plyr_1.8.4         tools_3.5.3       
 [7] lifecycle_1.0.0    tibble_3.1.3       gtable_0.3.0       pkgconfig_2.0.2    rlang_0.4.11       DBI_1.0.0         
[13] rstudioapi_0.10    yaml_2.2.0         parallel_3.5.3     withr_2.1.2        stringr_1.4.0      generics_0.0.2    
[19] vctrs_0.3.8        grid_3.5.3         tidyselect_1.1.1   data.table_1.14.0  glue_1.4.2         R6_2.4.0          
[25] fansi_0.4.0        purrr_0.3.2        magrittr_1.5       scales_1.0.0       ellipsis_0.3.2     stringdist_0.9.5.2
[31] assertthat_0.2.1   colorspace_1.4-1   utf8_1.1.4         stringi_1.4.3      lazyeval_0.2.2     munsell_0.5.0     
[37] crayon_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The issue

It seems the error is thrown in [repoverlap.R#136](https://github.com/imminfo/tcr/blob/master/R/repoverlap.R#L135-L136) which doesn't make sense at first sight. However, looking at your `sessionInfo()` reveals that the `tcR` package is outdated. There was a [change in 2.3](https://github.com/imminfo/tcr/commit/4d8870da8f2ae9271316639b1a5ae3850a9ab0b6#diff-3ea942fe2784cb32c09fe130f6253f5303a6f407c16a3044d17854dd581c999cR136) that modified this part of the code from

```r
## version 2.2.4
grouped_df(
  data.frame(...),
  vars = list(as.name("Sequence"))
)
```

to use a character (rather than a name) in the `vars` argument of `grouped_df()`.

```r
## version 2.3, Jun 7 2020 
grouped_df(
  data.frame(...),
  vars = "Sequence"
)
```

The old version will throw the exact error message mentioned in the question

```r
dplyr::grouped_df(mtcars, list(as.name("am")))
#> Error: `vars` must be a character vector.
packageVersion("dplyr")
#> [1] ‘1.0.5’
```

### The fix

`tcR` is no longer on CRAN, but I suggest you update the package from github and see if the problem still persists.

```r
remotes::install_github("imminfo/tcr")
```

Alternatively, you can switch to the "successor-package" `immunarch` which is on CRAN and still maintained. See [imminfo/tcr/README.md](https://github.com/imminfo/tcr/blob/master/README.md) for more details.

### How did this happen?

I am speculating here, but will reformulate this part as soon as the fix is confirmed.

Basically, `dplyr` had some recent changes that broke the logic in `tcR` 2.2.4. `tcR` fixed this in `2.3`. You probably ran `update.packages()` which updated `dplyr` but not `tcR` because `tcR` is no longer on CRAN. Therefore, the two package versions were no longer compatible.